# Magento - Need help diagnosing 'Search results page' whitescreen -

Tags: xml, magento

OK, so I just swapped themes for a new client and everything is working fine, except the search function.  No matter what gets searched, the results page white screen.

I did some googling and found a snippet to add to a file to help display the offending file, but unable to pinpoint it.

I cleared out the system.log file and recreated the error so I could see the whole process, and this is what was created (see below)

I'm totally stumped with this.  Any help would be appreciated.

The only error I see on here is:
    ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 136: parser error : Comment not terminated 
    <!-- My Applications
        <customer_account>
            <r  in /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444

...but I have no idea where to look for this as Update.php on line 444 reads nothing useful.

---

```
2015-03-16T12:02:59+00:00 DEBUG (7): <config/>
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): <?xml version="1.0"?><jstranslator></jstranslator>
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/core.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/directory.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/cms.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/blacknwhite/default/layout/catalog.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog_msrp.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/blacknwhite/default/layout/catalogsearch.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/payment.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales/billing_agreement.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sales/recurring_profile.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/cataloginventory.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/shipping.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/paypal.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/poll.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/review.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/reports.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/googleanalytics.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/paypaluk.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/contacts.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/sendfriend.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/rss.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/productalert.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]: Entity: line 136: parser error : Comment not terminated 
&lt;!-- My Applications
    &lt;customer_account&gt;
        &lt;r  in /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]:     &lt;!-- EOF My Applications--&gt;  in /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>function.simplexml-load-string</a>]:       ^  in /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/oauth.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/authorizenet.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/bundle.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/captcha.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/centinel.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/newsletter.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/pagecache.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/persistent.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/weee.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/xmlconnect.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/ebizmarts/abandonedcart.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/ebizmarts/autoresponder.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/magemonkey.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/iwd_all.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/iwd_opc.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/storelocator.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/blacknwhite/default/layout/slider.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/blacknwhite/default/layout/meigee/widgetoptions.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/mst_rma.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/contactsformcaptcha.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/moneybookers.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/strategery-infinitescroll.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/blacknwhite/default/layout/ajax.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/webforms.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/webformscrf.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): /chroot/home/example.com/html/app/design/frontend/blacknwhite/default/layout/local.xml
2015-03-16T12:03:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): <?xml version="1.0"?><widgets></widgets>
2015-03-16T12:03:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): <?xml version="1.0"?><widgets></widgets>
```

Comment: That means, that in one of your layout you do have a comment which is not closed. That is making your layout invalid in an XML meaning and thus Magento fail to display the page with incorrect layout. Try looking at `<!-- My Applications` in all of your layout (through your IDE or a command line search on your server) and you may identify the buggy layout.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  I searched and found the file without the closed comment. I closed it and saved. Now the system.log file is clean, but the page still breaks. 

I just noticed in firebug, I get an error:

"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://www.example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=Coat"

Is this htaccess?

Comment: Could be... but I guess you wouldn't see any page if that was really it. More likely another bug in you Magento combined with a write permission issue on folders. Maybe have a look at http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/install-privs-after

Answer (score 0):

So looking at your error message it appears that the layout file `productalert.xml` has some xml errors. It appears to have a comment that is opened but not closed afterwards.